# Connect to SASL Kafka broker in Java without TrustStore / KeyStore

Tags: java, apache-kafka, sasl

I'm trying to connect to a Kafka server in SASL in Java but it's not working. I'm not hosting the server, here are the only credentials I have:

```
- KAFKA_BROKER URL / PORT
- KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY
- KAFKA_USER
- KAFKA_PASSWORD
- KAFKA_TOPIC_NAME
- The Kafka certificate (ca.pem)
```

I was able to connect to the server in Python like that:

```
'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka-************.com:****',
  'ssl.ca.location':'/home/******/Downloads/ca.pem',
  'security.protocol':'sasl_ssl',
  'group.id': '*****',
  'sasl.mechanism':'SCRAM-SHA-256',
  'sasl.username':'******',
  'sasl.password':'******'
```

This is working fine, the thing is that the  'ssl.ca.location' parameter is not available in Java, i saw that people are using the KeyStore / TrustStore informations but I do not have these informations.

Do you know how I can provide the certificate information using Java ?

```
Here is my actual Java code:



  Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-*********.com:****");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "*****");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put("security.protocol","SASL_SSL");
    properties.put("sasl.mechanism","SCRAM-SHA-256");
    properties.put("sasl.jaas.config","org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username=\"******\" password=\"********\";");
    System.out.println("conf==  " +  properties.get("sasl.jaas.config"));
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
    
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

And this is the error I obtain:

```
  (sun.security.validator.ValidatorException) PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Do you know how the ca.pem file was created? You should be able to convert that into JKS files

Comment: Hello OneCricketeer, and thank you. I generated a keystore.jks file using keytool and I added these parameters to my java code:
    properties.put("ssl.keystore.location","C:\\Users\\******\\Downloads\\keystore.jks");
        properties.put("ssl.keystore.password","******");
But I got the same error (and I'm mixing ssl / sasl properties, not sure I'm doing things in the right way ;D)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with SASL_SSL configs, unfortunately, but I suggest trying to get kafka-console-producer working first

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution (sorry i'm not a Kafka expert). Thanks to the certificate file I generated a Truststore file (and not a keystore, the difference between them is still not clear to me). Below are the params I added to make i work:

```
    properties.put("ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm","");   properties.put("ssl.truststore.location","C:\\Users\\**\\Downloads\\keystore.jks");
    properties.put("ssl.truststore.password","****");
```

Thanks guys :)